# In October router, how to name endpoint, and get URL with the name

Tags: laravel, routes, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

When I give a name to my endpoint defined in my plugin's routes.php and try to access the endpoint by browser, it throws an error showing like;

```
Function name must be a string
/path/to/my/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php line 197
```

I followed [the October document](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/router#named-routes) and it looks something like below in `plugins/me/myplugin/routes.php`;

```
Route::get(
    'api/v1/my/endpoint',
    ['as' => 'myEndpoint', 'Me\MyPlugin\Http\MyEndpoint@show']
);
```

On the other hand, getting the URL by the name is fine with the both ways below.

```
$url = Url::route('myEndpoint');
```

or

```
$url = route('myEndpoint');
```

Then, I tried the way described in [Laravel 5.5 document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes), like below;

```
Route::get(
    'api/v1/my/endpoint',
    'Me\MyPlugin\Http\MyEndpoint@show'
)->name('myEndpoint');
```

Now, accessing the endpoint by browser is fine, but, getting the URL by the name gives an error.

```
Route [myEndpoint] not defined.
/path/to/my/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php line 305
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround, which is not documented but working fine.
In the routes.php define the endpoint like;

```
Route::name('myEndpoint')->get(
    'api/v1/my/endpoint',
    'Me\MyPlugin\Http\MyEndpoint@show'
);
```

Now, the endpoint is accessible and I can get URL by `Url::route` method and `route` helper.

However, I still expect those examples in my question work as well.
I didn't find out what are wrong with them, yet.

FYI, naming group works as described in the [October document](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/router#named-routes).

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'as' => 'api_v1::'], function () {
    Route::name('myEndpoint')->get(
        'api/v1/my/endpoint',
        'Me\MyPlugin\Http\MyEndpoint@show'
    );
});
```

Then, get URL like;

```
Url::route('api_v1::myEndpoint');
```

**Update (2020/02/28)**

Instead of using `name` method, giving the name as `as` option like below worked, as well.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'as' => 'api_v1::'], function () {
    Route::get('api/v1/my/endpoint', [
        'as' => 'myEndpoint',
        'uses' => 'Me\MyPlugin\Http\MyEndpoint@show',
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the routes.php define the endpoint like:

`Route::get('/api/v1/my/endpoint','Me\MyPlugin\Http\MyEndpoint@show')
->name('myEndpoint')`

For getting url  : `{{ route('myEndpoint') }}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can see that the difference in your answer from the one in my question is the slash at the beginning of the route path. (Twig function is actually the same as PHP function.)
But, I still get the error "Route [myEndpoint] not defined." by `route` function.